# What is the difference between machine independent and machine neutral?

Tags: terminology

what is the difference b/w machine independent and machine neutral????

Answer (score 2):

The words are different, the meaning is the same.

Namely: The bytecode produced can run on any machine that has the Java Runtime installed.

Comment: you may be right but i don't think so. there is a small diff. b/w them..
but i don't know.
if any one know then please tell me......